# Images wont appear in External CSS

Tags: css, image, html, aptana

Hi people this problem has been bothering me for very long.

My images in the external style sheet just wont appear. When i place it at the head of the html, it appears!
I am currently using Aptana Studio 3, but i think this of has nothing to do with Aptana.

Here is the code in my external css:

```
  .menuMainwrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 54px;
  z-index: 30;
  background: url("img/menuwrapper.png") center top repeat-x;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  }
```

And here is the html:

```
  <div class="menuMainwrapper">
  <ul class="menus menuMain">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

I have checked the directory already and it should be correct as it works if i place it in the head of the document. Oh ya and i am using Html 5 template from Aptana

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i am suspecting that the reference url to your image is not correct

try

```
background: url("../img/menuwrapper.png") center top repeat-x;
```

if your css is in /css folder and image is in /img folder

Answer (score 0):

check your image path. You can use Chrome developer tool. If the path is not correct, there should be errors at the bottom right corner.